# How to internationalize REST Spring-MVC application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I am new with spring and I still don't know well about hierarchy and terminology of `spring`. I am implementing a *RESTful* app with spring. After searching and reading about how to internationalize spring, I tried to do it in my app. But it seems to me it is not configured properly. Because I get exception. I would like to show you the screenshot of my project structure. And I would like to ask you why my `applicationContext.xml` show a problem exist.

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<!-- SPRING INTERNALIZATION CONFIGURATION -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" /> 
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="language" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javadoc of [`ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.setBaseNames()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html) says:

> Set an array of basenames, each following the basic ResourceBundle convention of not specifying file extension or language codes, but in contrast to ResourceBundleMessageSource referring to a Spring resource location: e.g. "WEB-INF/messages" for "WEB-INF/messages.properties", "WEB-INF/messages_en.properties", etc.

But you've placed your message properties files under src/main/resources in the Maven project structure, so they will end up at the root of the classpath instead (which means that even if Spring looked for them in the classpath, the /resources prefix you've used in the configuration would prevent Spring to find them).

So place the properties file under WEB-INF, and use `WEB-INF/messages` as the basenames property.

Comment: I updated my question. And I replaced my messages file under resources again. It is working now. However when I send request including "?language=tr" it returns me messages from en file. Pleaseee help!!!

Comment: That's another, different question. Thus post another, different question. And mark this answer as accepted, since it solved your problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272031/internationalize-rest-spring-mvc-application