# Internationalize REST Spring-MVC application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

Actually the question  [asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267122/how-to-internationalize-rest-spring-mvc-application/) continue. According to my spring-servlet.xml configuration for internationalization, I can not change the language of request. When I send request including "`?language=tr`" it returns me messages from `en` file. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- SPRING INTERNALIZATION CONFIGURATION -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" /> 
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
    </bean>
    <mvc:interceptors>    
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
        p:paramName="language" />
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    </bean>

    <!-- Declare a view resolver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
            p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

**my applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- spring frameworka properties dosyasını tanıtma -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/applicationContext.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property> 
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    </bean>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
        <aop:include name="myLogger"/>
    </aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

    <bean id="myLogger" class="sow.webservices.aop.SowLoggerAOP"/>
    <bean id="personService" class="sow.webservices.services.PersonService" />
    <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.
     For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="sow.webservices" />

    <!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
    Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

    <!-- Loads MongoDB configuraton -->
    <import resource="mongo-config.xml"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: have you created a file `WEB-INF/messages_tr.properties` and other language specific properties files

Answer (score 0):

Rather make sure that you added the **localeChangeInterceptor** bean within the interceptors properties of your **handleMapping** bean as follows:

```
<bean id="handlerMapping"vclass="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
  <property name="interceptors">
    <list>
      <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Or try to register the `LocaleChangeInterceptor` as an **mvc:interceptor**:

```
<mvc:interceptors>    
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
    p:paramName="language" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

You need to add the mvc namespace schema (xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc") in the root declaration of the spring context file so it may look as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
...

</beans>
```

Comment: I have already used first configuration you advice and it is already in my question. When I ad <mvc:interceptors> xml shows error as The prefix "mvc" for element "mvc:interceptors" is not bound. what am I supposed to do?

Comment: by the way I am getting this warning as well
Class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping' is marked deprecated

Comment: Make sure to add the *xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"* declaration in your root beans declaration. I've edited the answer, BR.

Comment: when I add <mvc:interceptors>..., handlerMapping makes a problem and ask for localeChangeInterceptor.

Comment: Try to remove the <property name="interceptors">...</property> declaration from the handlerMapping.

Comment: I did what u said and I update d my question. It is really not working :(

Comment: Can I see how are accessing the internationalized messages?

Comment: Sure. inside jsp I am doing like that : <spring:message code="deneme"/><br> and this show only en message even if I change lang. Inside java code for example in my controller 
@RequestMapping(value="/deneme", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String deneme(ModelAndView mw, Locale locale) throws PersonNotFoundException{
  String msg = ms.getMessage("deneme", null, "Deault Message!", locale);
  System.out.println("LANGUAGE : "+msg);
  return "deneme";
 }
And this just show "default message"

Comment: It seems to weird since I can't see any problem neither with your configuration nor the way you are getting the internationalized messages. Could you please update the main thread description and past all the applicationContext.xml descriptor?

Comment: Otherwise, try to explicitely set the name and the max age of the used cookie:

    <property name="cookieName" value="emiliaLocale"/>
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="604800"/>

Check if this cookie is created with some client side inspection tool, if it is so, then fulfil a request with a parameter "language=tr" and check if the the cookie value has changed.

Comment: I updated the question by adding applicationContext.xml

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49331/discussion-between-emilla-and-tmarwen)